# Send Data from SQLite to appServer using POST,OKHttp

Tags: android, sqlite, post, okhttp

I have an **SQLite** Db which stores call logs. Each entry has a *number*, *date*, and *duration*. I have seen that there are many ways we can send the data to the app server. As a JSON String and send one by one from an ArrayList of model class objects.
***Which is the correct way to approach this***? And *how can I create a JSON from these data*, *I have done as much as getting these data to an ArrayList of objects*. since each entry has many data, I am confused about how to do this.

```
    public ArrayList<PhNumber> getCallLogs() {

    ArrayList<PhNumber> callLogList;
    callLogList = new ArrayList<PhNumber>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM callInfo where syncStatus = '" + "no" + "'";

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            callLogList.add(new PhNumber(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1),
                    cursor.getString(2),
                    cursor.getString(3),
                    cursor.getString(4)));

            Log.e("DbHelper:getCallLogs", callLogList.toString());
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return callLogList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which is the correct way to approach this?

There is not any one solution . It depends on your use case scenario.

For making JSON , you can do this after getting your data in `ArrayList<PhNumber> callLogList`

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

  for (int i = 0; i < callLogList.length(); i++) {
 JSONObject jsonobject= new JSONObject();
 jsonobject.put("data1",callLogList.get(i).get); //I dont know the field name of your PhNumber so fill accordingly
 jsonobject.put("data2",callLogList.get(i).get);

 jsonArray.put(jsonobject);
}
```

Comment: Should I convert jsonArray to a string before adding it to the body, to Post?

Comment: @Lenzman  it depends on your api . if they expect string  then yes

Comment: @Lenzman it it solved your problem . you can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) for this, a library that is very easy to use, saves lot of time and code. Serialization and HTTP requests are handled seamlessly using Retrofit.

[please refer to this article for simple understanding of Retrofit](https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial)

Comment: Cool,I will check it out